# Python OpenCV cv2.WaitKey() and Windows 10

Tags: python, opencv

I made a small python program to capture images from the screen. It is designed to stop when either the Esc or 'a' keys are pressed. It is capturing images as programmed but doesn't stop when I press either the Esc or 'a' keys. My OS is Windows 10 and I'm using Python 3.6.4 (Anaconda). Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import mss
from PIL import Image

#Creates an endless loop for high-speed image acquisition...
while 1:
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        #Get raw pixels from the screen
        sct_img = sct.grab(sct.monitors[1])

        #Create the Image
        img = Image.frombytes('RGB', sct_img.size, sct_img.bgra, 'raw', 'BGRX')

        #Show the Image
        cv2.imshow('test', np.array(img))

        #Kill-switch: press the 'Esc' or 'a' keys to exit the program
        if (cv2.waitKey(33) == 27) or (cv2.waitKey(33) == ord('a')):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What if you press those buttons like a dozen times in a row? Does it ever stop?

Comment: Nope, only CTRL+C stops it.